# Cuda Out Of Memory With Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to make a classifier on googleNet Inception Architecture. But I am getting a weird Out Of Memory Error. Please help me through this.

```
2019-01-11 16:08:43.136845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2123 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-11 16:08:43.255541: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6281232384 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-01-11 16:08:51.609811: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6281232384 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-01-11 16:08:58.098275: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6281232384 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-01-11 16:09:02.965511: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6281232384 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-01-11 16:09:08.340921: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6281232384 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-01-11 16:10:00.857988: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:00.881572: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2019-01-11 16:10:00.964002: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:00.970572: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 7730940928
2019-01-11 16:10:01.038286: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 6957846528 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:01.044442: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6957846528
2019-01-11 16:10:01.051304: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:01.057950: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2019-01-11 16:10:11.065267: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:11.101282: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2019-01-11 16:10:11.125436: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:868] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-01-11 16:10:11.140062: W .\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/cuda_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
```

Allocation Summary by tensorflow is as follows.

```
2019-01-11 16:10:11.153245: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:267] Allocator (cuda_host_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 5.85GiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.163437: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.179841: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.198029: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.211066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.223903: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.233066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.242287: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16384):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.251250: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (32768):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.267965: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (65536):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.277803: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (131072):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.286811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (262144):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.298442: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (524288):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.308577: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1048576):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.317588: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2097152):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.326986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4194304):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.335589: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8388608):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.348752: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16777216):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.357372: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (33554432):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.366123: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (67108864):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.377628: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.387885: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-01-11 16:10:11.397278: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:613] Bin for 5.85GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State:
```

I am using NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1080 3GB  and 8 GB RAM. 
Also For more Information about the data is as follows

```
Training Images Shape :- (16016, 224, 224, 3)      
Training Images Labels :- (16016, 163)
Testing Images Shape :- (14939, 224, 224, 3)
Testing Images Labels :- (14939, 163)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your GPU ran out of memory. Which essentially means that your data is larger than the memory can hold. Try lowering your batch size and see if it works.

Comment: I put my batch size from 32 to 5 but still I encounter the same error 

history = model.fit(X_train,X_test,validation_data=(y_train,y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=5)